# Javascript on Firefox: Accessing binary data from html object possible?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, object

On an html page I have an `<object>` that hosts a pdf. 
I would need to access the binary data of the pdf via Javascript, but I cannot figure out how
to accomplish that. I get access to the object element itself but cannot think of a method for getting the data in it.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Just one word .. WHY ? why are you using javascript for this ? why do you want to do this at all ?

Comment: I am running an algorithm which takes the pdf the user is currently reading in the browser as input.

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the binary from an `object` tag, but you can make an AJAX request to the server and get it as [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) by using the new `responseType` attribute:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("get", "somefile.pdf", true);
http.responseType = "arraybuffer";

http.onload = function(e)
{
    if(http.response)
    {
        // http.response contains the file
    }
};

http.send(null);
```

Note that this method only works in newer browsers and is obviously restricted by the Same-Origin-Policy.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I tried to read the data from the object tag because of Same-Origin-Policy problems. As you may already recognized I am very new to JS and AJAX. What I want to accomplish is to be able to get access to any pdf file the browser would reach by user interaction. Would there be a way you could think of?
Tanks, Armin

Comment: There is no way to get around this policy; it would be useless otherwise.